# Default Data type in Java

Tags: class, custom-data-type

Assume that I have a class called Test

```
public class Test{
     int a;
     public String b;
     protected int c;
     private int d;}
```

In this case, what is the default data type of int a(private or public)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

It's package protected or package private, I don't know whats the correct terminus.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. It's the "default" data type (yes, it's actually called "default").